# Transferring files with batch?

Tags: email, batch-file

I wanted to have a user submit input to a batch file I wrote on a remote machine, and then invisibly have the input saved to a .txt and transferred to my remote machine. I know how to take the input and have it save itself to a .txt, but I don't know how to get the file where I can view it. I tried having the batch code run a Powershell script to use $send, but that didn't work and then I tried to figure out how to use a FTP server. Can anyone give me a FTP server that will work for this purpose and some commands to try it with or a link to an alternate method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean inter- or intranet file transfer? In intranet you can copy to share, at internet you could use the users email client maybe?

Comment: I want it to be invisible to the user, so whatever method seems easiest. I've heard there are ways to put it on a "cloud", so to speak, and just download it. I honestly have no idea

Comment: IMHO this has a bit of a malware scent to it.  I'm not sure what SO rules are regarding questions on that topic.

Comment: i have to agree foxidrive, how does user submition go together with being invisible in a serious way?

Comment: Haha, no it's not Malware. I just want it to be easy for my less tech-savy friends. I don't want them to have to really interact and mess something up. It doesn't need to be "invisible", but it has to just happen.